# many1 no longer works with Parsec 3.x

Tags: haskell, parsec

After updating to Parsec 3.1 from 2.x, code using many1, such as `word = many1 letter` fails with

```
No instance for (Stream s m Char) arising from a use of `letter'
```

I found a mailing list post claiming that adding `{-#LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` to the top of the source file would solve the problem, but it did not.

Comment: I would have claimed the same thing as that post.  Maybe you are missing a mandatory space before LANGUAGE?

Comment: @Zak, `many1` doc on hackage has very little information. can you tell me, what this function does?

Comment: @MadhavanKumar - the documentation says "many1 p applies the parser p one or more times. Returns a list of the returned values of p." I'm not sure what's unclear, or did the documentation say something else previously?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't forget to add a space before `LANGUAGE`.

Instead of turning off the monomorphism restriction, you can also write an explicit type annotation.